# Expression.PropertyOrField returns "not a member of type 'System.String'" for string property

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to build expressions dynamically for a rules engine and things were going very well until I tried to allow nested types and properties to be specified as operands. Sample:

**ExpressionBuilder**

```
public Expression BuildExpression<T>(string propertyName, Enums.Operator ruleOperator, object value, ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
    {
        ExpressionType expressionType = new ExpressionType();
        Expression body = parameterExpression;

        foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            body = MemberExpression.Property(body, member);
        }

        var leftOperand = MemberExpression.PropertyOrField(body, propertyName);
        var rightOperand = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(value, value.GetType()));
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = expressionType.GetType().GetField(Enum.GetName(typeof(Enums.Operator), ruleOperator));
        var expressionTypeValue = (ExpressionType)fieldInfo.GetValue(ruleOperator);

        return CastBuildExpression(expressionTypeValue, value, leftOperand, rightOperand);
    }
```

**RuleEngine**

```
public Func<T, bool>[] CombineRules<T>(Criterion[] criteria)
    {
        List<Func<T, bool>> list = new List<Func<T, bool>>();
        foreach (var criterion in criteria)
        {                    
            ExpressionBuilder expressionBuilder = new ExpressionBuilder();
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
            Expression expression = expressionBuilder.BuildExpression<T>(criterion.PropertyName,
                    criterion.Operator_, criterion.Value, param);
            Func<T, bool> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, param).Compile();
            list.Add(func);
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

**Criterion**

```
public class Criterion
{
    private bool propertySet;
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Enums.Operator Operator_ { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
```

**MemberModel**

```
public class MemberModel
{
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
    public PersonalDetailsModel PersonalDetails {get; set;}
}
```

**PersonalDetailsModel**

```
    public class PersonalDetailsModel
{
    public int PersonalDetailsId { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Middlename { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string GenderType { get; set; }
    public string SalutationType { get; set; }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to pass in nested properties as a left operand, i.e. PropertyName="PersonalDetails.FirstName" into ruleEngine.CombineRules(criteria.ToArray());

I get "'PersonalDetails.Firstname' not a member of type 'System.String'", despite it clearly being so. I've been stuck on this for a while now, any idea what might be causing it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here

```
    Expression body = parameterExpression;

    foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        body = MemberExpression.Property(body, member);
    }
```

you already processed the property path, so this

```
  var leftOperand = MemberExpression.PropertyOrField(body, propertyName);
```

make no sense and is the source of the exception. In your example, `body` contains something like `p.PersonalDetails.FirstName` (String) and the above line is trying to build something like `p.PersonalDetails.FirstName.PersonalDetails.FirstName`.

Use `var leftOperand = body;` instead.

You can shorten the whole property path processing by using simple

```
var leftOperand = propertyName.Split('.')
    .Aggregate((Expression)parameterExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);
```

Comment: Oh my, what a silly oversight. Bloody Fridays. Thank you so much!

Comment: How can we achieve the same for List<PersonalDetailsModel> ?

Comment: @VamsidharMamillapalli This builds (or can build) dynamically single item filter, e.g. `Func<PersonalDetailsModel, bool>` or `Expression<Func<PersonalDetailsModel, bool>>`, which can be passed to `Where` methods of respectively `IEnumerable<PersonalDetailsModel>` (which `List<PersonalDetailsModel>` is) or `IQueryable<PersonalDetailsModel>`.